# TINYINT data type to store signed numbers in mysql

Tags: c++, mysql, tinyint

I have a table MACRecord in MYSQL. I have 3 fields declared as `TINYINT(4)` (`RSSI1, RSSI2, RSSI3`) with a default value of `0`. I use it to store signed negative values i-e `-90, -84` etc. I am trying to understand how much length each number is taking in the column. I have a `c++` code to output length of each column in bytes as follows:

```
lengths = mysql_fetch_lengths(result);
num_rows = mysql_num_rows(result);

for(i = 3; i < num_fields; i++)
{
     if (strstr(fields[i].name, "RSSI") != NULL) 
     {
         printf("Column %u is %lu bytes in length.\n",
                    i, lengths[i]);
     }
```

So now for example if columns 3, 4 and 5 which are my RSSI's columns contain values such as -90, 0(default), -83, i get the output as follows:

> Column 3 is 3 bytes in length
>
> Column 4 is 1 bytes in length.
>
> Column 5 is 3 bytes in length

I don't understand why having a value of for example `-90` in my `RSSI`'s columns which were declared as `TINYINT(4)` which can only store `1 byte` values is displaying as having `3 bytes` of data? The default value of `0` makes sense. If I describe my table I can see that the data type is `TINYINT` but still it says values `3 bytes` in length.

```
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra  |   
| RSSI1     | tinyint(4)  | YES  |     | 0       |        |
| RSSI2     | tinyint(4)  | YES  |     | 0       |        |
| RSSI3     | tinyint(4)  | YES  |     | 0       |        |
```

I am a bit confused. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> don't understand why having a value of for example -90 in my RSSI's columns which were declared as TINYINT(4) which can only store 1 byte values

in binary ...

> is displaying as having 3 bytes of data?

in decimal.

"-90" is three bytes in decimal, and -90 is one byte of binary.

Comment: Hi, I am still not sure about this. My confusion is when i declared RSSI column to be a TINYINT data type, i expected it should only store 1 byte of data. Why does it say 3 byte for a storage of a value such as -70 or -90? Can you please provide further clarification? Thanks

Comment: Is it storing the sign i-e (-ive - ) in one byte and the next 2 numbers as separate 2 bytes? Is that is why it is giving me 3 bytes? But this does not make sense to me. -90 can be stored in 1 byte as 1010010?

Comment: I've told you. "-90" is three bytes. "-", "9", and "0", in decimal, whereas 1010010 is binary.